# Disable Fedora 26 Installer from connecting to OpenH264 Repos

Tags: linux, fedora, kickstart

We regularly install Fedora behind a firewall without Internet access for the system. The install is fully automated with kickstart and normally takes 10-15 minutes. All packages are installed from a local mirror of the Fedora repos that we keep behind the firewall. With Fedora 26, we found it is now taking nearly an hour to install, a regression from our previous Fedora 24 and 25 installs using nearly identical kickstart files. It appears that Fedora 26 spends 45 minutes repeatedly trying to access codecs.fedoraproject.org, a repo site for the OpenH264 codecs which we have no use for. The installer only proceeds after it gives up 45 minutes later and then proceeds to install normally.

Loading up the ISO and attempting a manual, interactive install shows something similar. For about 45 minutes, the Installation Source and Software Selection menus are grayed out with the message "Downloading group metadata..." One it times out, the user can proceed and finish the install.

How do we disable Fedora 26 from trying to connect to codecs.fedoraproject.org?

**Update:** This appears to be a known issue with the Fedora 26 installer and is discussed here:
https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/pull/1145

Comment: Disable the repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-cisco-openh264.repo by setting `enabled=0` perhaps?

Comment: @nick This is during the initial install of Fedora. I need a line I can add to kickstart.

Comment: Once installed, that repo is indeed already set to enabled=0, but it still hung during install.

Comment: how about excluding the package that contains these codecs.

Comment: @mdpc Nothing we do has any use for proprietary software. We install with a fairly minimal amount of packages. Nothing should be getting installed from this repo. In fact, the whole point behind this hang is that is can't access that repo, but it never throws any errors about missing packages during the install.

Comment: We are using the same kickstart file approximately since at least Fedora 22. We don't add packages to that list as everything else beyond the core needs is installed after first boot so I'm not sure where this dependency came from.

Comment: Note that this software is not proprietary. We would not have included it in this way were it not open source.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like a similar issue is still on Fedora 38, but it's only a few minutes of waiting, not 45, before it gives up reaching the Internet repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a fix that will land for F27. In the meantime, I think you should be able to

```
rm /etc/anaconda.repos.d/fedora-cisco-openh264.repo
```

in the `%pre` section of your kickstart.